# PDFKit - locate image in center

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

Using [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/docs/images.html) on node.js:

```
 var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit')
 var doc = new PDFDocument()
 doc.image('images/test.jpeg')
```

How can I centerize an image added to the PDF?

Is it optional to do it using PDFKit or do I need to use another library?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found an indirect way to solve the problem - simply calculate the center and locate the picture there:

```
 doc.image('images/test.jpeg', (doc.page.width - imageWidth) /2 )
```

Comment: note that this would work only if the image size is smaller than the document size

Comment: This should definitely be a native part of pdfkit if only width is specified and align is an attribute of the mixin.

Comment: imageWidth should be in the PDF.

How to know the image width in PDF? It's not the same as the HTML.

Answer (score 16):

Using [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/) on node.js: We can center the image using following code

```
doc.image('path/to/image.png', {
  fit: [250, 300],
  align: 'center',
  valign: 'center'
});
```

Comment: The `align` and `valign` in this example center the image in the rectangle defined by `fit` not in the page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this, this code place your image at middle of the line

```
let imageWidth = 180 // what you wants
doc.image('path/to/image.png', 
        doc.page.width/2 - imageWidth/2,doc.y,{
        width:imageWidth
      });
```